# Google Analytics Phonegap plugin outdated and not working

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, analytics

I have just recently got interested in the Google Analytics plugin but found out since it has been released in May that it has been destroyed, discontinued and just recently reinstated in the official phonegap gitHub.

While it works like a charm for Android it does not for iOS.

I got to solve most of the bug but (outdated way to do an import) I am still getting this error :

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"OBJC_CLASS$_GANTracker", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

can someone help please ?

**EDIT:**

as my own answer shows I managed to get the plugin to run on iOS and Android. However, I haven't find a way to get some quick and decisive test to ascertain the tracking, can anyone help at all ?

Comment: the developers don't know why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation to my issue other there:

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/issues/29#issuecomment-2367223